# difference between Visual Studio and Qt

Tags: visual-studio, qt

Can somebody please explain what is the main difference between visual studio and Qt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) is an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), a piece of software that combines a text editor and other programming facilities (integrates a compiler, testing suite and more). This is where you write you code and debug it.

[QT](http://qt.nokia.com/products) is a [library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) - it is a library of software intended to be used by programmers to build up on. You can use it when writing code, by writing code for and with it.

You can use Visual Studio to type in and write applications with the QT library, but not the other way around.

You could create an IDE using a library such as QT - Visual Studio is using WPF as its graphics library. You would still write the IDE with an editor first...

Comment: from your comparison I understood that it's like opengl, I can write program on visual studio using opengl library, am I wrong?

Comment: @helloWorld - exactly right. QT is like OpenGL as both are libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/developer-tools/)? That is an IDE, like Visual Studio, but is optimised for creating Qt programs. If you're using Qt a lot then use Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

QT is a cross-platform application and UI [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework).